# Maintain data integrity and consistency when performing sql batch insert/update with unique columns

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, validation, transactions

I have an excel file that contains contents from the database when downloaded. Each row is identified using an identifier called id_number. Users can add new rows on the file with a new unique id_number. When it is uploaded, for each excel row,

- When the id_number exist on the database, an update is performed on the database row.
- When the id_number does not exist on the database, an insert is performed on the database row.

Other than the excel file, data can be added or updated individually using a file called report.php. Users use this page if they only want to add one data for an employee, for example.

Ideally, I would like to do an insert ... on duplicate key update for maximum performance. I might also put all of them in a transaction. However, I believe this overall process have some flaws:

- Before any add/updates, validation checks have to be done on all excel rows against their corresponding database rows. The reason is because there are many unique columns in the table. That's why I'll have to do some select statements to insure that the data is valid before performing any add/update. Is this efficient on tables with 500 rows and 69 columns? I could probably just get all the data and store all of them in a php array and do the validation check on the array, but what happens if someone adds a new row (with an id_number of 5) through report.php? Then suppose the excel file I uploaded also contains a row with an id_number 5?  That could probably destroy my validations because I can not be sure my data is up to date without performing a lot of select statements.
- Suppose the system is in the middle of a transaction adding/updating the data retrieved from the excel file, then someone from report.php adds a row because all the validations have been satisfied (E.G. no duplicate id_numbers). Suppose at this point in time the next row to be added from the excel file and the row that will be added by the user on report.php have the same id_number. What happens then? I don't have much knowledge on transactions, I think they at least prevents two queries changing a row at the same time? Is that correct?

I don't really mind these kinds of situations that much. But some files have many rows and it might take a long time to process all of them.

One way I've thought of fixing this is: while the excel file upload is processing, I'll have to prevent users using report.php to modify the rows currently held by the excel file. Is this fine?

What could be the best way to fix these problems? I am using mysql.

Comment: 500 rows is ok.  69 rows is getting high, but not "bad".  Having multiple unique keys on a table is rather strange (but not "wrong"); I suggest you try to 'fix' this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really need** to allow the user to generate their own unique ID then the you could lock the table in question while you're doing you validation and inserting.

If you acquire a write lock, then you can be certain the table isn't changed while you do your work of validation and inserting.

```
`mysql> LOCK TABLES tbl_name WRITE`
```

don't forget to

```
`mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;`
```

The downside with locking is obvious, the table is locked.  If it is high traffic, then all your traffic is waiting, and that could lead all kinds of pain, (mysql running out of connections, would be one common one)

That said, **I would suggest a different path** altogether, let mysql be the only one who generates a unique id.  That is make sure the database table have an auto_increment unique id (primary key) and then have new records in the spreadsheet entered without without the unique id given.  Then mysql will ensure that the new records get a unique id, and you don't have to worry about locking and can validate and insert without fear of a collision.

In regards to the question as to performance with a 500 records 69 column table, I can only say that if the php server and the mysql server are reasonably sized and the columns aren't large data types then this amount of data should be readily handled in a fractions of a second.  That said performance can be sabotaged by one bad line of code so if your code is slow to perform, I would take that as a separate optimisation problem.

Comment: yes, I do have a primary key. But the id_number I am talking about is a specific number given by the company for their employees. Also, there are other columns that are unique.

Comment: Well, if you don't have a choice about the specific number, then I'd suggest going for the lock tables option.  There are some other things that you could do that are less heavy handed.  Like putting a flag in the database that the report.php checks to verify if there is a spreadsheet currently being imported.  And then the report.php could either reject the user request (nicely) or just wait for some reasonable amount of time and retry the request.